File not found at new WindowsPtyAgent when using pty for a spawn process of running another file through cmd
I am working on a Desktop app with electron framework which always has a terminal open  the output of the processes run is shown in that terminal. I am using node-pty for this but when I try to pass a file using spawn process to be run on cmd, it just gives me the following error of file not found:  enter image description here
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process 
Uncaught Exception: 
Error: File not found: 
at new WindowsPtyAgent 
\node modules\node-pty\lib\windowsPtyAgent.js:80:36) 
at new WindowsTerminal 
\node modules\node- pty\lib\windowsTerminaI js:51 :24) 
at Object.spawn 
\node modules\node-pty\lib\indexjs:29:12) 

at IpcMainlmpl.<anonymous> (main.js88:25)  
at IpcMainlmpl.emit (node:events:519:28 
at WebContents.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:82388) 
at WebContents.emit (node:events:519:28) 

the file is there and it works without pty.
Initially, I was expecting for the output of cmd to be shown in my shell process which is being run through pty. I have a pty process which is used all the time for a terminal I tried removing that terminal changing the order of them being called but the only thing that worked was to remove pty and just use a spawn process which gave me the correct result I was expecting in the beginning. I want all the results to be shown in the same terminal only and not another div.
